# Is it possible to add BLOB Wide Memo field to a nexusdb table using a query?

Tags: delphi, nexusdb

I am developing a database comparing tool using delphi and nexusdb. I tried to add a BLOB Wide Memo field to a table using query. but i could not find the correct data type. i tried follow queries.

```
ALTER TABLE Test ADD COLUMN TestField BLOBWideMemo;
ALTER TABLE Test ADD COLUMN TestField NATIONAL CHARACTER LARGE OBJECT;
ALTER TABLE Test ADD COLUMN TestField BLOB Wide Memo;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
ALTER TABLE Test ADD COLUMN TestField NCLOB
```